# Numerical libraries and special function of complex parameters

Tags: complex-numbers, numerical-methods

I tried to calculate some integral numerically. It contain hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ where $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers. I can't find numerical library which contains hypergeometric function with complex parameters. Does anybody tell me name of numerical library which can be done it?

I know a little bit C, C++, python, FORTRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I faced this problem quite recently, I tell what I used.

The [first link](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookfpdf/f6-12.pdf) is in "Numerical Recipes"; on their site, you can recover older versions for free .

The [second link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Hypergeometric-Functions.html) if from GNU .

Comment: GNU library contains only hypergeometry function of real parameters and  where $b=a^*$. It does not suit me. I will try to use Numerical Recipes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. If you go to the site of NR, you can access for free the books of previous editions.

Comment: I have one more question  Claude Leibovici. I find not only book but also numerical library nr.h with examples. This library contain hypergeometry function. Does it available for free too?

Comment: Where did you find the library ?

Comment: I found it in the Internet. As an example https://yandex.ru/search/?text=Press%20W.H.%2C%20Teukolsky%20S.A.%2C%20NR%20in%20C%20%28program%20only%29%20download&lr=65&clid=1917061